# Instagram Graph API - media_product_type not showing STORY

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, instagram-story

I currently have the below API response for one of our instagram pages using the Graph  API that includes media_product_type, even though our Page has a STORY we are not seeing it come through, but we do see FEED and IGTV, see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/) for the documentation on this field. Has this happened to anyone else?

```
/12334555/media?limit=100&period=lifetime&fields=name%2Ccaption%2Clink%2Cshortcode%2Ccomments_count%2Cmedia_type%2Cpermalink%2Clike_count%2Ctimestamp%2media_product_type&access_token='blah'
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the stories endpoint (not media)

eg:

```
{baseUrl}/{version}/{instagramUserId}/stories?fields=caption,media_url,timestamp,permalink,username,media_type,like_count,comments_count,shortcode,thumbnail_url,video_title,media_product_type&limit=10&access_token={accessToken}
```

Note: story info is only around for 24 hours, so ideally you polls for infor and then setup the webhook to receive the final counts before the story dissapears.